# When should I make objects package-private or public?

Tags: java, oop, object

I have two classes: **Foo.class**, **FooContainer.class**, and **FooContainerUser.class**

**Foo.class**

```
class Foo {
    private Map<String, String> fooData;

    public Foo () {
        fooData = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getFooData() {
        return new HashMap<>(fooData);
    }
```

**FooContainer.class**

```
public class FooContainer {
    private Map<String, Foo> fooMap;

    public FooContainer () {
        fooMap = new HashMap<>()
    }

    // First getter implementation
    public Map<String, Foo> getFooMap() {
        return new HashMap<>(fooMap);
    }

    // Second getter implementation
    public Map<String, String> getFooData(String fooName) {
        Foo selectedFoo = fooMap.get(fooName);
        if (selectedFoo != null) {

            return selectedFoo.getFooData();

        } else return null;
    }
```

Suppose the classes Foo and FooContainer is in the same package, and a class called FooContainerUser is in a package parenting the package where the previous classes reside.

The FooContainerUser class is supplied a FooContainer instance. It needs to get the data from the Foo instances the FooContainer contains for some reason e.g. to display the data.

Which leads me to my question:

1. Should I make the Foo class public and make FooContainerUser use the first getter implementation of the FooContainer class, or should I instead make the Foo class package-private and make FooContainerUser use the second getter implementation of the FooContainer class?
2. Suppose the second getter implementation is preferred. What if I make more class that extends the Foo class with more but different fields for each subclass, and different subclasses needs to be stored in the FooContainer? Should I implement more getter methods in the FooContainer specific for each subclasses of Foo?

Sorry if I made mistakes on how I explained my problem. I am relatively new to programming and I want to learn the basic design patterns.

Comment: You should declare everything as restrictively as possible.

Comment: @user207421 So, what is your opinion regarding my questions?